# how to use php explode in laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
 $user = $this->user;
            $user->name = $request['name'];
            $user->email = $request['email'];
            $user->password = $request['password'];
            $user->save();

$name = explode(' ' ,$user->name);

$profile= $user->userdetail()->create([
                'user_id' => $request->input('id'),
                'first_name' => <the value of the first exploded string>
'last_name' => the value of the secondexploded string
                ]);

            return redirect('confirmation');
        }
```

how to split two words using explode function in php? For example i registered wth name of JOhn doe I want to create in my userdetail table the first_name of john and last_name of doe. How can i do it/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP explode function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932505/php-explode-function)

Comment: Other answers are exact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an array of strings, so you can access elements by using keys:

```
$profile = $user->userdetail()->create([
              'user_id' => $request->input('id'),
              'first_name' => $name[0],
              'last_name' => $name[1]
          ]);
```

Comment: What if the user inputs a name like Antonio da Silva ? that is 3 words how am i gonna loop through that ?

Comment: What if the user inputs a name like Antonio da Silva ? that is 3 words how am i gonna loop through that ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code

```
$full_name = "John Doe";
$name = explode(' ',$full_name);
$first_name = $name[0];
$last_name = $name[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way :

```
<?php

   $ip = "fname lname"; 
   $iparr = preg_split("/[\s,]+/",$ip); 
   echo "$iparr[0]";
   echo "$iparr[1]";

?>
```

But explode is good(faster) than preg_split. ;)